# Eliminating need for ALL(*) parsing in ANTLR 4 Grammar

Tags: antlr4

I am writing an ANTLR 4 grammar for a language that will have `switch` statements that do not allow fallthrough (similar to C#). All `case` statements must be terminated by a `break` statement. Multiple `case` statements can follow each other without any code in between (again, just like in C#). Here is a snippet of the grammar that captures this:

```
grammar MyGrammar;

switchStmt : 'switch' '(' expression ')' '{' caseStmt+ '}' ;

caseStmt : (caseOpener)+ statementList breakStmt ;

caseOpener : 'case' literal ':'  
           | 'default' ':' 
           ;

statementList : statement (statement)* ;

breakStmt : 'break' ';' ;
```

I left out the definitions of `expression` and `statement` for brevity.  However, it's important to note that the definition for `statement` includes `breakStmt`. This is because `break` statements can also be used to break out of loops.

In general the grammar is fine - it parses input as expected.  However, I get warnings during the parse like "line 18:0 reportAttemptingFullContext d=10 (statementList), input='break;" and "line 18:0 reportContextSensitivity d=10 (statementList), input='break;" This makes sense because the parser is not sure whether to match a `break` statement as `statement` or as `breakStmt` and needs to fall back on ALL(*) parsing.  My question is, how can I change my grammar in order to eliminate the need for this during the parse and avoid the performance hit? Is it even possible to do without changing the language syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `breakStmt` reference from the end of `caseStmt`, and instead perform this validation in a listener or visitor after the parse is complete. This offers you the following advantages:

1. Improved error handling when a user omits the required break statement.
2. Improved parser performance by removing the ambiguity between the `breakStmt` at the end of `caseStmt` and the `statementList` that precedes it.

I would use the following rules:

```
switchStmt
  : 'switch' '(' expression ')' '{' caseStmt* '}'
  ;

caseStmt
  : caseOpener statementList?
  ;

statementList
  : statement+
  ;
```

Comment: Thanks. Just one follow-up on why I should use `caseStmt*` and not `caseStmt+`. Would I ever have a switch statement without any case statements, or are you saying that I should handle that as a separate error when traversing the parse tree with my listener or visitor?

Comment: @MrCodeMnky Definitely the latter. I've seen empty switch statements generated during a code generation process (for example), and allowing that in the parser but including a specific semantic error greatly improves the "friendliness" of your compiler.